# Generacion de Horas con un for Visual Basic .net

Tags: vb.net

Tengo este código que me llena en un datagrid las horas cada 15 minutos empezando desde las 08 am

¿Cómo haría si quiero generar las mismas Horas pero una fila más por cada hora? ejem: en este caso habría dos filas con 08 am y dos filas con 8:15 así sucesivamente.

```
Private Horario4(52) As String

Private Sub LlenarHoras()
    Dim minuto As Integer
    Dim Horas As String = ""
    Dim contador As Integer
    For hora As Integer = 8 To 20
        For minuto = 0 To 45 Step 15
            If hora < 10 And minuto < 10 Then
                Horas = "0" + hora.ToString() + ":" + "0" + minuto.ToString()
            Else
                If hora < 10 And minuto >= 10 Then
                    Horas = "0" + hora.ToString() + ":" + minuto.ToString()
                Else
                    If hora >= 10 And minuto < 10 Then
                        Horas = "" + hora.ToString() + ":" + "0" + minuto.ToString()
                    Else
                        If hora >= 10 And minuto >= 10 Then
                            Horas = "" + hora.ToString() + ":" + minuto.ToString()
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            End If
            Horario4(contador) = Horas
            contador = contador + 1
        Next
    Next 
End Sub
```

Comment: Si vas a trabajar con horas, debes usar `DateTime`. De esa manera tienes un método `AddMinutes` y el código es más sencillo y limpio.

Answer (score 0):

> Debes duplicar el lugar donde asignar el valor al horario, y sumar dos
>   veces en el contador

```
Private Horario4(104) As String

Private Sub LlenarHoras()
    Dim minuto As Integer
    Dim Horas As String = ""
    Dim contador As Integer

    For hora As Integer = 8 To 20
        For minuto = 0 To 45 Step 15
            If hora < 10 And minuto < 10 Then
                Horas = "0" + hora.ToString() + ":" + "0" + minuto.ToString()
            Else
                If hora < 10 And minuto >= 10 Then
                    Horas = "0" + hora.ToString() + ":" + minuto.ToString()
                Else
                    If hora >= 10 And minuto < 10 Then
                        Horas = "" + hora.ToString() + ":" + "0" + minuto.ToString()
                    Else
                        If hora >= 10 And minuto >= 10 Then
                            Horas = "" + hora.ToString() + ":" + minuto.ToString()
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            End If
            Horario4(contador) = Horas
            contador = contador + 1
            Horario4(contador) = Horas   'Aquí se duplica                
            contador = contador + 1  'y sumas otro

        Next
    Next 
End Sub
```